# WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1 Key Manager access token translation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, key-management, wso2-identity-server

I have an OpenIdConnect Identity Provider hooked up to the API Manager. I am able to authenticate and retrieve an access token using authorization_code and implicit grant types. The access token created by the OpenIdConnect IP is different than the access token returned by the API Manager Gateway. As I understand it, the key manager won't pass-through the access token from the OpenIdConnect IP but will store it and send a generated access token from the API Manager. The API Manager access token should reference the stored token from my OpenIdConnect IP.

Here is the problem... When I try to connect to a resource endpoint on the API Manager Gateway with the WSO2 Access token, the OpenIDConnect IP access token never gets passed back to the backend server. How can I get the OpenIdConnect IP access token to the backend servers?

Comment: not clear exactly what you wanted here. could you please add mote details to describe your use case? API Manager use oauth token endpoint to generate access tokens. what do you mean by access token translation anyway?

Comment: sure... sorry for not making it clear in the first post...

We have our API Manager hooked up/federated with a 3rd Party OpenIdConnect Identity Provider. This Identity Provider is attached to our own user base. We are using the OpenIdConnect/Oauth federation setup for our identity provider.

When our identity provider creates an access token (for a particular user) it sends it back to the API Manager. The API Manager is then generating a new access token instead of using the one from the federated identity provider. How can i get that federated access token back to the application?